# Gaussian concentration of measure, equivalent definitions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

I need some help going between two equivalent definitions.

First some notation :

$\bullet$ For $A\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ and $r>0$ define what is called the r-blowup of $A$ as \begin{equation}
A_r = \{ x \in \mathcal{X} : d(x,A)<r \}.    
\end{equation}

$\bullet$ We have a metric probability space $(\mathcal{X},d,\mu)$, i.e $(\mathcal{X},d)$ is a Polish space, and $\mu$ a probability measure on its Borel sets.

Now I am going to give two definitions for  $\mu$ satisfying a Gaussian concentration of measure. Can anyone show how to go from one definition to the other (of course with a change of constants).

---

$\textbf{Def.1}$
$\mu$ is said to have Guassian concentration on $(\mathcal{X},d)$ if there exists $K,\kappa >0 $ such that

\begin{equation}\label{Gauss concentration}
\textit{whenever}~~\mu(A)\geq \frac{1}{2} ~~ \textit{it implies} ~~ \mu(A_r)\geq 1-K e^{-\kappa r^2}    
\end{equation}

$\textbf{Def.2}$
We say $\mu$ has Gaussian concentration of measure if there exists $K,\kappa >0$ and some $r_0>0$, such that
\begin{equation}
\textit{whenever}~~\mu(A)\geq \frac{1}{2} ~~ \textit{it implies} ~~ \mu(A_r) \geq 1-Ke^{-\kappa(r-r_0)^2} ~~ \forall r\geq r_0
\end{equation}

---

[1, Page 103] claims that we can go between the two with a change of constants, how? Note going from $\textbf{Def.1}$  to
$\textbf{Def.2}$ is fine just replace $r$ by $r-r_0$.

[1] Raginsky, Sason. Concentration of Measure Inequalities in Information Theory, Communications and Coding. 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it is easy to go from Definition $1$ to Definition $2$.

Let $K$, $\kappa$, and $r_0$ be the constants in Definition 2. We will now find constants $K'$ and $\kappa'$ for Definition $1$. Set $K' := \max(K,1)e^{4 \kappa' r_0^2}$ and $\kappa':= \kappa/4$ to be the constants in Definition 1. We will show that these constants suffice by considering two cases:

Case 1: $r \in [0,2r_0]$. We have that
$$
K' \exp(- \kappa'r^2) = \max(K,1)\exp(\kappa'(4r^2_0 - r^2)) \geq 1, $$
and thus the desired inequality $\mu(A_r)\geq 1 - K' \exp(- r^2)$ holds trivially.

Case 2: $r \geq 2r_0$.
We have the following series of inequalities:
$$ \begin{aligned}1 - \mu(A_r) &\leq K e^{- \kappa (r - r_0)^2} \\
&\leq K e^{- \kappa r^2/4}\\
&\leq K'e^{- \kappa r^2/4} = K'e^{- \kappa' r^2},
\end{aligned}  $$
where we used that $K \leq K'$ and $|r - r_0| \geq r/2 $ for $r \geq 2r_0$.